# Waitable timer reset period

Tags: c, winapi

I have a waitable timer with a reset time of 24hours. However the timer will be delayed around 3minutes every day it's been going. So I'm wondering what could cause this. I'm using the [lPeriod](http://puu.sh/aO4mN.png) of `SetWaitableTimer` which specifies the time to be in milliseconds. Here's the code i use to set the timer.

```
int SetTimr(LARGE_INTEGER* fire, node* cursor, LONG reset)
{
    // Create an unnamed waitable timer.
    cursor->hTimer = CreateWaitableTimer(NULL, false, NULL);

    if (cursor->hTimer == NULL)
    {
        printf("CreateWaitableTimer failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    // Set a timer to wait for N seconds.
    if (!SetWaitableTimer(cursor->hTimer, fire, reset, NULL, NULL, true))
    {
        printf("SetWaitableTimer failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

`fire` is the time when it's supposed to signal which there has never been a problem with.

`reset` is the time until the timer should fire again which is set as a 
constant to

`#define DAY 86400000` which i understand would be exactly 24hours.

I check the timers every 250ms which shouldn't have this big effect on the delay. So I'm wondering if anyone has any thoughts on how I'm using the timers. I realize that I can just set the timer anew for the desired time but i don't understand why this doesn't work properly.

Comment: What does MSDN have to do with this question?

Comment: If you want the timer to go off at the same time each day, consider setting it to that specific time (each day) rather than using a period.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Userspace timers are general-purpose timers, and as such, are not guaranteed to be "super accurate". It's only really guaranteed that a timer will wait *at least* whatever interval is specified before firing.

A possible implementation might be to have a "master" timer go off every millisecond, and increment all "slave" timer counters. When a timer's counter reaches the specified interval time, it triggers the event. Depending on how the "master" timer is configured, it may take *slightly* longer than a millisecond between triggers (in your case, in the order of a few microseconds longer). This slight delay adds up, resulting in the 3-minute drift from your 24-hour timer.

In your case, because you want to wait an entire day between events, you might be better off periodically querying the system time, or use [`QueryPerformanceCounter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644904%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: ``Depending on how the "master" timer is configured, it may take slightly longer than a millisecond between triggers (in your case, in the order of a few microseconds longer). This slight delay adds up, resulting in the 3-minute drift from your 24-hour timer.`` I'm not using a master timer though, it's a single timer with a 24hour reset period that's drifting by 3min or so.

Comment: @user3785768 by "master" timer I mean something implemented by the kernel that responds directly to millisecond intervals. It's not something you have control over.

Comment: Oh i see. That would explain the delay. I'll have a look at the method you suggested. Thank you for the help